Running SqlPlus in PowerShell Not accepting Parameters
I am using PowerShell to run a sql script via SqlPlus. I need to pass two dates parameters into the sql script.
If I type everything out directly, it works fine:
sqlplus userName/Password @C:\myFolder\myScript.sql 27-May-2024 29-May-2024

However, I want to be able to pass parameters into the sqlplus command, like so:
$login = "userName/Password" 

$SQLFile = "C:\myFolder\myScript.sql"

# The sql file requires two date parameters
$startDate = (Get-date).AddDays(-3).ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy")
$endDate = (Get-date).AddDays(-1).ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy")
$SQLFileParms = "$startDate $endDate"

sqlplus $login @$SQLFile $SQLFileParms

SqlPlus just doesn't seem to take my PowerShell variables. I can't figure out how to get this to work.

Change $SQLFile = "C:\myFolder\myScript.sql" to $SQLFile = "@C:\myFolder\myScript.sql" and change the sqlplus invocation to sqlplus $login $SQLFile $startDate $endDate
